# gRPC Keep stream alive

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I am experimenting with gRPC for long-lived streaming session as I need to guarantee message ordering from server to client.

I have the following .proto:

```
service Subscriber {
    rpc Subscribe(SubscriptionRequest) returns (stream SubscriberEvent);
}
```

My current service (hosted in ASP.NET / .NET 5.0) looks like this:

```
public class SubscriberService : Subscriber.SubscriberBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<SubscriberService> _logger;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, IServerStreamWriter<SubscriberEvent>> _subscriptions = new();
    private int _messageCount = 0;
    private Timer _timer;

    public SubscriberService(ILogger<SubscriberService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _timer = new Timer(o => TimerCallback(), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    private void TimerCallback()
    {
        Broadcast($"Current time is {DateTime.UtcNow}");
    }

    public override Task Subscribe(SubscriptionRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<SubscriberEvent> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        _subscriptions.TryAdd(request.ClientId, responseStream);
        return responseStream.WriteAsync(new SubscriberEvent() {Id = 0, Message = "Subscribe successful"});
    }

    public void Broadcast(string message)
    {
        var count = ++_messageCount;
        foreach (var sub in _subscriptions.Values)
        {
            sub.WriteAsync(new SubscriberEvent() { Id = count, Message = message });
        }
        _logger.LogInformation($"Broadcast message #{count}: {message}");
    }
}
```

My client only receives the initial 'Subscribe Successful' message, but never those triggered by the timer. Not do I get any exceptions when calling WriteAsync.

Am I trying to use gRPC for something it was never designed to do (a SignalR/WebSocket substitute), or am I merely missing something obvious?

Comment: I have no experience with gRPC in .NET. From what I know based on using gRPC in other languages, when you return from the function implementing the streaming method, the stream gets closed. So, when you return from `Subscribe`, the stream gets closed. If you try printing the error returned from `sub.WriteAsync` in `Broadcast`, you should see an error saying the `stream is closed`.

Comment: @EaswarSwaminathan: That would certainly explain it. WriteAsync does not return anything else than an awaitable Task, and there is nothing to indicate what the problem is in the logs either. I would expect WriteAsync to throw an exception if the stream was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a long-running gRPC streaming, you have to wait for a client to say the connection is closed. Something like this:

```cs
while (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // event-based action
    responseStream.WriteAsync(new SubscriberEvent() {Id = 0, Message = "Subscribe successful"});  
}
```

Comment: This indeed the answer. It threw me off for a moment :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the previous answer is doing busy-wait. So I want to show you an async version of it.

```
public override Task Subscribe(RequestMessage, IServerStreamWriter<ReplyMessage> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
 {
    // your event-based code here
    
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    context.CancellationToken.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), false);
    return tcs.Task;
 }
```

BTW, I think I have been doing a project just like yours. And I have used Observables, Subjects, and ReplaySubjects from [Rx.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive). These are very helpful for event-based code.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I did a while loop but with a await Task.Delay instead of the accepted answer. It ended up being easier just to pass the stream to a subscription manager outside the service.